# Linearization vs Jacobian

Tags: linear-algebra, jacobian, linearization

I am dealing with the Nonlinear Schrodinger Equation and my task is to analyse the stability of the equilibrium solution.

The equation in fiber optics takes the following form:

$u_z = \phi u + \frac{1}{2}u_{tt} + |u|^2u$.

where $u$ is a vector in the $t$ axis and $\phi$ is a constant.

For finding the equilibrium point, I set $u_z=0$ and calculated the solution numerically. That works well.

A dissertation I am reading said that I have to linearize the above equation about the fixed point as :

$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Delta u = \mathscr{L} (\Delta u)$ where $\mathscr{L}$ is the linearized operator. The dissertation then says that I have to evaluare $\mathscr{L}$ at the fixed point and find the eigenvalues. This works.

But my question is - why not calculate the Jacobian of the right side of the nonlinear equation and then calculate its eigenvalues instead? I tried that, verified the accuracy of the Jacobian by testing its second order convergence and calculated the eigenvalues. It wasn't the same as the eigenvalues of the linearized operator.

So what is the fundamental difference between the linearized operator and the Jacobian of the nonlinear equation?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the Jacobian in this context?

Comment: $u$ is a vector. The Jacobian would be the traditional Jacobian with dimension $N\times N$ where $N$ is the length of $u$. If this is not what you were looking for, please let me know how I can clarify the question.

Comment: How do you deal with $u_{tt}$ then? And what is $\phi$, by the way?

Comment: I have edited the question a little. $u_{tt}$ is $u(z,t)$ differentiated twice w.r.t $t$. Usually through spectral techniques. $\phi$ is a constant.

Comment: Yes, I know what the notation $u_{tt}$ means (how it's approximated numerically is irrelevant here). But I still can't make any sense at all of what you're trying to do. Are you trying to take partial derivatives of the $k$th component on the right-hand side, with respect to the variable $u_i$? Then, again, *how do you deal with $u_{tt}$*? The right-hand side is not a function of just the variables $(u_1,\dots,u_n)$. It's a *functional*, taking the function $u$ as input and producing a vector, where also *derivatives* of $u$ influence the outcome.